# How to load libraries upon initialization of custom action server in RASA

Tags: rasa

I am creating a bot in RASA that calls custom actions using the custom action server. My custom action simply takes the user's sentence, does some processing aided by a python library and returns a new sentence.

The issue I have is that upon calling the custom action, the libraries are being loaded in which takes up time and causes a timeout (which I can probably fix by increasing timeout, but is still not efficient).

Is there a way in RASA, upon starting the custom action server, to load all libraries at the start (prior to calling any actions)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest fix is to make a quick curl request to the server to trigger the action right when you launch it. You can also silently send a trigger intent when your assistant first launches like so: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/reaching-out-to-user/#external-events